# How to get aliases from Freebase?

Tags: php, freebase, mql

I just want to get from Freebase the different aliases a person can have. My PHP query is :

```
$query = array(
    array(
        'id' => NULL, 
        'alias' => NULL, 
        'name' => "Barack Obama", 
        'type' => "/people/person"
    )
);
```

The result is:

```
Array ( 
    [code] => /api/status/error 
    [messages] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [code] => /api/status/error/mql/type 
            [info] => Array ( 
                [expected_type] => /people/person 
                [property] => alias 
            ) 
            [message] => Type /people/person does not have property alias 
            [path] => 
            [query] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [alias] => 
                    [error_inside] => . 
                    [id] => 
                    [name] => Barack Obama 
                    [type] => /people/person 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
    [status] => 200 OK 
    [transaction_id] => cache;cache01.p01.sjc1:8101;2012-05-11T16:17:29Z;0082 
)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full name of the property is /common/topic/alias.  Unless the property belongs to the type you're working with or is a property of /type/object, you need to fully specify it.

You can either change the type to /common/topic (since you don't appear to be using /people/person at all) or change the property to be /common/topic/alias.

Comment: Great Tom, I get the aliases for the first time! The only problem is that I also get the following error message: `code`[message] => Unique query may have at most one result. `code`. Do you know why?

Comment: Note that I get the error even if I replace "alias":null for "alias":[]. I don't understand why.

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is without more context.  There should be an "error_inside":"." pair returned in the query at the point where the problem is.  Your change to "alias":[] should have fixed it if the problem was occurring at that point, but perhaps there's an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Here is the output (I cut some of the elements of the array): Array ( [code] => /api/status/error [messages] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => /api/status/error/mql/result [info] => Array ( [count] => 10 [result] => Array ( [0] => Barack Hussein Obama, Jr. [1] => Barack Hussein Obama [2] => President Obama ... [9] => Obama, Barack ) ) [message] => Unique query may have at most one result. Got 10 [path] => alias [query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [alias] => [error_inside] => alias [id] => [name] => Barack Obama [type] => /common/topic ) ) ) ) [status] => 200 OK [transaction_id] =>... )

Comment: Values for the alias property can occur multiple times.  Your query should be "alias":[] not "alias":null.  If you want more than just English aliases, use something like "alias":[{"lang":null,"value":null}]