# How to get aliase of something in freebase

Tags: freebase

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555098/how-to-get-aliases-from-freebase) but I don't get my answer from there.

Suppose we want to get any other names for MID=m/0220q6 (which is ETH-Zurikh). We want all the aliases for ETHZ which are :

```
ETHZ
ETH Zürich
Swiss Federal Institute of Technology Zurich
...
```

Basically everything related to this MID, via "/common/topic/alias".

I tried the following and similar MQL. But it does seem to work. Any idea?

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "/common/topic/alias": null,
  "type": "/en/eth_zurich"
}]
```

or

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "/common/topic/alias": null,
  "mid": "m/0220q6"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd query should work except you're missing a / at the start of the MID. It should be:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "/common/topic/alias": [],
  "mid": "/m/01dyk8"
}]
```